# I was not change my location but onlocationchanged give different location coordinate

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I was steady at my position but when onLocationChanged() event called after my time interval not give same location coordinates.

```
Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);


public void initialiseLocationRequest() {
        sLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();             sLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        sLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        sLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10 * 1000);
    }


 // set LocationListener and listen in onLocationChanged        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                LocationHelper.sLocationRequest, this);
```

### output :-

> 09-28 17:40:55.478 6703-6703/com.ai.terminal D/MapsActivity:
>   onLocationChanged: Latitude :- 23.0506133 Longitude :-72.51852 09-28
>   17:41:06.517 6703-6703/com.ai.terminal D/MapsActivity:
>   onLocationChanged: Latitude :- 23.0508033 Longitude :-72.51854 09-28
>   17:41:18.451 6703-6703/com.ai.terminal D/MapsActivity:
>   onLocationChanged: Latitude :- 23.05087 Longitude :-72.518645 09-28
>   17:41:30.470 6703-6703/com.ai.terminal D/MapsActivity:
>   onLocationChanged: Latitude :- 23.0508667 Longitude :-72.51864 09-28
>   17:41:42.451 6703-6703/com.ai.terminal D/MapsActivity:
>   onLocationChanged: Latitude :- 23.0508667 Longitude :-72.51864

Comment: provide more clarity in your question dear

Comment: Please edit it correctly!

Answer (score 1):

OnLocationChanged() will be called if the current location update is not matching with last known location.

The updated location will be changed for every minTime (in my case it was 1000 milli sec) and also if device moved minDistance (in my case 0 meters) distance.

That means it is very volatile and it flickers. However you can ignore digits after two decimal places.

Note : The accuracy also depends on your device.

Comment: Instead of ignoring digits I would suggest using [setSmallestDisplacement()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) to avoid getting callbacks for every tiny change in the location.

Comment: yes this is right but I put my mobile on table and run my application. I was not move my mobile (Steady at position) then also give different location.

Comment: Yeah..but here the case is your device constantly talks to the satellites for GPS services which keep changing their position. Along with this there are many interferences which cause this. However, you can expect the accuracy upto 2 or 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Use different device to test. This might help.